# Sympy/mpmath/gmpy error while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, sympy, mpmath, gmpy

EDIT: This is a sympy bug. I have moved the discussion to https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7457

I have a Python program that uses `sympy` to perform some core functionality that involves taking the intersection of a line and a shape. This operation needs to be performed several thousand times, and is quite slow when using the default `sympy` pure Python modules.

I attempted to speed this up by installing `gmpy 2.0.3` (I have also tried with `gmpy 1.5`). This does lead to the code speeding up somewhat, but when using `multiprocessing` to gain a further speed-up, the program crashes with a `TypeError`.

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 376, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\geometry\point.py", line 91, in __new__
    for f in coords.atoms(Float)]))
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\simplify\simplify.py", line 3839, in nsimplify
    return _real_to_rational(expr, tolerance)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\simplify\simplify.py", line 3781, in _real_to_rational
    r = nsimplify(float, rational=False)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\simplify\simplify.py", line 3861, in nsimplify
    exprval = expr.evalf(prec, chop=True)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\evalf.py", line 1300, in evalf
    re = C.Float._new(re, p)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\numbers.py", line 673, in _new
    obj._mpf_ = mpf_norm(_mpf_, _prec)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\numbers.py", line 56, in mpf_norm
    rv = mpf_normalize(sign, man, expt, bc, prec, rnd)
TypeError: ('argument is not an mpz', <class 'sympy.geometry.point.Point'>, (-7.07106781186548, -7.07106781186548))
```

The program works fine when run in a single process using `gmpy` and when run without `gmpy` using `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Has anyone run into this sort of problem before? The program below reproduces this problem:

```
import sympy
import multiprocessing
import numpy

def thread_function(func, data, output_progress=True, extra_kwargs=None, num_procs=None):
    if extra_kwargs:
        func = functools.partial(func, **extra_kwargs)

    if not num_procs:
        num_procs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_procs)
    results = pool.map_async(func, data.T)
    pool.close()

    pool.join()
    return results.get()

def test_fn(data):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    circle = sympy.Circle((0,0), 10)
    line = sympy.Line(sympy.Point(0,0), sympy.Point(x,y))
    return line.intersection(circle)[0].evalf()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = numpy.vstack((numpy.arange(1, 100), numpy.arange(1, 100)))

    print thread_function(test_fn, data) #<--- this line causes the problem
#    print [test_fn(data[:,i]) for i in xrange(data.shape[1])] #<--- this one runs without errors
```

Comment: Doesn't multiprocessing use `pickle`? Maybe gmpy objects are not picklable.

Answer (score 1):

I've verified that `gmpy` objects are picklable and that `mpmath.mpf` objects that use `gmpy` are also picklable.

The error occurs when the `man` argument to `mpf_normalize()` is not a `gmpy` object. If I force `man` to be an `mpz`, then I no longer get an error. But the answer is different from the single process version.

Single process version:

Point(-223606797749979/50000000000000, -223606797749979/25000000000000)

Multiple process version:

Point(-7.07106781186548, -7.07106781186548)

Both the types used in Point() are different (rational vs. float) and the values are different (-223606797749979/50000000000000 is -4.47213595499958).

I'm still researching and will update this answer if I discover the root cause.

**Update #1:** The differing values were caused by an error in the example code. The threaded function was passed different values than the non-threaded version.

I'm still tracking down why multiprocessing triggers the exception. I've reduced the problem to the following example:

```
import sympy
import multiprocessing
import numpy

def thread_function(func, data, output_progress=True, extra_kwargs=None, num_procs=None):
    if extra_kwargs:
        func = functools.partial(func, **extra_kwargs)

    if not num_procs:
        num_procs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_procs)
    results = pool.map_async(func, data)
    pool.close()

    pool.join()
    return results.get()

def test_fn(data):
    return sympy.Point(0,1).evalf()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_size = 10
    print [test_fn(None) for i in xrange(1, test_size)] #<--- this one runs without errors
    print thread_function(test_fn, [None] * (test_size - 1)) #<--- this line causes the problem
```

Comment: The bug in the example code is that data is being iterated column-wise in the multiprocessing example. I've fixed this in the question.

Comment: Note that as this is a sympy bug, I'm going to move discussion there. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7457